# Issue in using useFocusEffect inside function component

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to use "useFocusEffect" inside a functional component and getting the following error:

> Couldn't find a navigation object. Is your component inside a screen.

I am using the following approach

```
    useFocusEffect(
        React.useCallback(() => {
        console.log("Salil RenderFeedContent useFocusEffect ")      
       
        }, [])
      );
```

My Component :

```
    export default RenderFeedContent = (props) => {

    useFocusEffect(
        React.useCallback(() => {
          console.log('Salil  useFocusEffect RenderFeedContent')
        }, [])
      );
//Rest of the logic is to render the component  .
```

Code from where the component is getting rendered . This is class based component and I have access to the navigation prop till this point:

```
const FeedPost=props=>{
        const { navigation } = props
        return(
                <RenderFeedContent {...props} navigation = {navigation} content={props.content} />

        )
    }
```

[Please refer to following link for all details](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/function-after-focusing-screen/)

Versions:

> @react-navigation/native: 5.7.3

> @react-navigation/core: 3.7.6

Please help. Am I missing something obvious . I have list of Videos and I want to pause the currently playing video when navigating away from the same. I guess this is because of the version of react navigation I am using .In case more details are required please let me know.

Comment: Why is half your code commented? How/where are you rendering your component? This almost certainly has nothing to do with the hook usage.

Comment: Actually the commented code is one approach I tried using the navigation prop but navigation doesnt  have useFocusEffect method . I am trying to use this inside a functional component which is not being passed the navigation props explicity .

Comment: And could I know the reason for the immediate down vote had ? If there are concerns with question quality I would have fixed them .

Comment: Downvotes are reversible. Your question lacks important context (like the component definition and how it's being rendered) needed to answer it. Edit in the missing information and it will likely go away. Don't take it personally.

Comment: Added more details In case something is ambiguous will add more information .

Comment: Well, you are showing us *part* of your component definition. Keep going. *You need to show us how you're rendering your component. Again*, the error message you posted is almost certainly a problem with how you're rendering your component, not how you're defining it. This code:  `navigation.useFocusEffect({` is an "undefined is not a function" error, and makes no sense. Please either get rid of it or explain it better. Unfortunately there is not enough here to make your question answerable, but I appreciate you trying to make it better.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226529/discussion-between-salil-kaul-and-jared-smith).

Comment: I will keep on digging but the issue seems to be that we arent using the React Navigation correctly